# ShellExecute path error in XP - can't find file

Tags: windows, batch-file, vbscript

I have a batch file that I want to execute with administrative privileges. I have created a vbscript file to launch as admin using this code:

```
Set UAC = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
UAC.ShellExecute "mybat.bat", "", "", "runas", 1
```

When I double click my vbs, it shoots an error:

[image: Windows cannot find bat]

and I tried:

```
Set UAC = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
UAC.ShellExecute "<path>\mybat.bat", "", "", "runas", 1
```

and

```
Set UAC = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
UAC.ShellExecute "mybat.bat", "", "<path>", "runas", 1
```

and neither of these worked.. nothing happened.

This works just fine on Windows 7+ but doesn't seem to work at all on Windows XP. I found an article about a known issue on this back in 2004 but that was in Sp1 and I have Sp3 so it should be fixed.

I put in the path directory into the environmental variables but when I launch the vbs, it does nothing. A command window doesn't even pop up. I thought the working directory was assumed relative if there wasn't a specified directory.

Is there anything I can do to launch my bat file as administrator, or is there anyway to fix this vbscript issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `runas` verb in XP. Which makes sense because there is also no UAC in XP.

In XP you would typically use the `open` verb and expect the user to be an administrator. If the user is not an administrator then you need to use the `runas` command line tool to run the new cmd process as an administrator user. That would require you to know an administrator user name and password. So it's really best to leave it to the user to deal with that.

So, the conclusion is that you should use the `runas` verb for Vista and later, and the `open` verb for XP and earlier.

Comment: +1 Cool info, is there any documentation on this "verb"al difference?

Comment: @Rich I'm not sure. The ShellExecuteEx docs are one possible source but IIRC they do not mention runas.

Answer (score 1):

RunAs was in XP. It allowed you to choose what user account to use (in Vista it elevates).